# Has anyone managed to map the side buttons on a Steelseries Rival 700 mouse?

Tags: mouse

I'm trying to map the side buttons on my Steelseries Rival 700 to copy/paste. I did some research and most posts were pointing to xbtn but I don't think that's available anymore.

Also tried [rivalcfg](https://github.com/flozz/rivalcfg) but that can't be used to map the side buttons.

Any ideas on what I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: Try installing [piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper), it looks like it supports some Steelseries Rival types.

Comment: I tried piper as well but piper supports what [libratbag supports](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/tree/master/data/devices) and unfortunately the Rival 700 isn't on that list. I guess the best thing I could try is to duplicate a file from a similar mouse and see if I can make it work somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to map my side buttons on my Rival 700 in Ubuntu using piper.

I created a new device file based on the Rival 600 one which is supported, I changed the device name and USB id. After this piper found the mouse and I was able to do the changes, even though there was no visual representation of the mouse in the interface, all worked well.

This is how the newly created steelseries-rival-700.device in /usr/share/libratbag file looks like:

```
[Device]
Name=SteelSeries Rival 700
DeviceMatch=usb:1038:1700
Driver=steelseries

[Driver/steelseries]
DeviceVersion=3
Buttons=7
Leds=8
DpiRange=100:12000@100
MacroLength=1
```

Hope this helps people with the same issue. I checked and LED configuration also works.